# Font Awesome Icons showing as squares between navigation [Chrome Only]

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, font-awesome

There is an issue with our main website in a very remote circumstance.

If the user clicks on a link, then very quickly clicks the Back Button on Chrome, the Font Awesome icons will appear as **squares**.

We are using a locally stored instance of *Font Awesome*, and this issue only occurs maybe once every 5 attempts, but I would still like to fix this issue.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPrvL.png)

Comment: Well, the correct way would be to replace icon fonts with SVG icons. But depending on the size of the site, that might be a larger task...

Comment: I think the .woff format font is missing. Please check...
=> fontawesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is just [FUOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content). In your case fonts are  loaded with delay. For some reasons they are no cached (maybe developer tools are opened?).

You can try to reproduce this error by [simulating](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/network-performance/network-conditions) slow internet connection on chrome.
If you do it you would probably also see this squares.

You would probably need to implement preloader screen and only show content of page every asset is loaded. You will have to create some div which will cover whole page, and then remove it when document is ready.

Here's [example](https://ihatetomatoes.net/create-custom-preloading-screen/).

Answer (score 0):

Reorder the font formats in your @font-face so that WOFF is placed before TTF and SVG. SVG fonts render better in the browsers that support them. Therefore make it default.

Answer (score 0):

put all fonts file like .ttf,woff,woff2,also put SVG of it. Make sure that check give a font  family name also. Also check fonts calling path. May be its helps you :)